# How can I make my search relevancy better with Google Vision?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am using Google Vision API to get the objects and labels from an uploaded image. For some images the Objects and labels are not relevant. Is there any way to make it better?

I am expecting a better solution from anyone.